# NserviceBus start Event

Tags: ninject, nservicebus

I want to configure Dependency Injection with Ninject in my application, and my project is a Subscriber class library. What is the first event produced by NserviceBus for initialize my kernel and modules bindings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is in NServiceBus.Host.exe.config define your EndpointConfigurationType

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="EndpointConfigurationType" value="<Assembly>", <Namespace>"/>
  </appSettings>
```

After this define a class

```
 public class EndpointConfiguration : AsA_Server, IWantCustomInitialization, IConfigureThisEndpoint     
 {
   public void Init()
   {
         /do Ninject stuff here
   }
 }
```

Hope this makes sense. Let me know if you need more clarification. Good luck.

Comment: The appsettings entry isn't necessary since NSB will scan you assemblies for classes implementing IConfigureThisEndpoint

Comment: Yes that is true but for readably purposes its good practise to add this